# Using for and if to iterate through rows in openpyxl

Tags: python, for-loop, openpyxl

I have been searching around but could not find an obvious answer to my problem.

I am using openpyxl to read data from sheets with `read_only = True` through the following call:

```
for row in ws.rows:
    for col in row:
          npAvailability[row_idx, col_idx] = col.value
          col_idx += 1
    row_idx += 1
```

However, I want to skip the first row in the sheet and was wondering if it is possible to do this in the first `for` call that may look something like this:

```
for row in ws.rows if row_idx >= 1:
```

Obviously this does not work.  The only other way is to do the `if` after the row call eg:

```
for row in ws.row:
    if row_idx >= 1:
         for col in row:
             etc...
```

This seems cumbersome.  Guidance would be appreciated.

P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about slicing off the first row?

```
for row in ws.rows[1:]:
    ...
```

NOTE: this is untested but look right from the [source code](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html).

Comment: Nope.  `row in ws.rows[1:]:
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Paul, not sure what version you're using but this works for me on openpyxl version 2.4.8.  `ws.rows` returns a tuple rather than a generator.

Comment: On latest openpyxl, this worked 

"for row in ws.rows:
row[0].value"

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first row by using the iterator directly.

```
iter = ws.iter_rows
# Start at row 2
for row_idx in range(2, ws.max_row):
    for col_idx,col in enumerate(iter(str(row_idx)), 1):
        for cell in col:
            npAvailability[row_idx, col_idx] = cell.value
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `iter_rows` method was required, as with example below:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(test_file)
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    print(row)
```

I was using openpyxl version 3.0.0